# How to unpack BTreeMap item tuple from an iterator in Rust?

Tags: dictionary, rust

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4a4ced365b02a23511f7d5cc26742a60&version=stable&backtrace=0) is example code:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: BTreeMap<u8, Vec<u8>> = BTreeMap::new();
    let idx = map.iter_mut().find(|t| {
        let (&k, &mut v) = t;
        v.is_empty()
    });
    idx.map(|t| {
        let (&k, &mut v) = t;
        v.push(5);
    });
}
```

Errors:

```
<anon>:6:13: 6:25 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&(&u8, &mut collections::vec::Vec<u8>)`,
    found `(_, _)`
(expected &-ptr,
    found tuple) [E0308]
<anon>:6         let (&k, &mut v) = t;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The type of tuple is `&(&u8, &mut collections::vec::Vec<u8>)` so I expect it to be unpackable with following:

```
let (&k, &mut v) = *t;
```

But

```
<anon>:10:28: 10:30 error: type `(&u8, &mut collections::vec::Vec<u8>)` cannot be dereferenced
<anon>:10         let (&k, &mut v) = *t;
                                     ^~
```

How to unpack it and use for mutable purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the error message:

```
 expected `&(&u8, &mut collections::vec::Vec<u8>)`,
    found `(_, _)`
(expected &-ptr,
    found tuple) [E0308]
```

The compiler expects to match against a reference, but the code does not provide such. Change the binding to `let &(&k, &mut v) = t`. Then you get a bunch of other errors:

1. Matching using `&mut foo` means that `foo` will have the `&mut` stripped off, and then the resulting value will be *moved* to `foo`. This is because it is a pattern match, just like how `let Some(foo) = ...` "strips off" the `Some`.
2. You can't move the `Vec` because it's owned by the `BTreeMap`, so you need to take a reference to it. This is done with the `ref` keyword, not the `&` operator.
3. Normally, you'd also do the pattern matching directly in the closure argument, not in a second variable.
4. Since `map` transfers ownership of the item to the closure, you can just give that a `mut` binding, no need for any references.
5. As `k` is unused, it's idiomatic to replace the name with an underscore (`_`).

```
let idx = map.iter_mut().find(|&(k, ref v)| {
    v.is_empty()
});

idx.map(|(_, mut v)| {
    v.push(5);
});
```

---

> use for mutable purposes

If you mean "how can I mutate the value in the closure to `find`", the answer is "you can't". Find returns an immutable reference to the iterated item (`&Self::Item`):

```
fn find<P>(&mut self, predicate: P) -> Option<Self::Item> 
    where P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool
```

Even though your `Self::Item` might be a mutable reference, an immutable reference to a mutable reference is still immutable.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks also for the result code and for noticing that `ref` is not `&`, I thought it is the same things.